# How use "Where-Object" condition with '[PScustomobject]'?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have some code:

```
$output = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name       = $ws.UsedRange.Columns.Item(1).Value2
    Department = $ws.UsedRange.Columns.Item(3).Value2
}

$output | GM
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                                  
----        ----------   ----------                                  
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)              
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                           
GetType     Method       type GetType()                              
ToString    Method       string ToString()                           
Department  NoteProperty System.Object[,] Department=System.Object[,]
Name        NoteProperty System.Object[,] Name=System.Object[,]
```

I need to sort and filter my `$output`, but I can't. Nothing happens. Probably doing something wrong.

```
PS> $output

Name                             Department                                     
----                             ----------                                    
{Numbers, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7...}      {Sales,IT,Accounting,Developers...}
```

And my condition:

```
PS> $output | Sort-Object Department -Descending | Where-Object {$_.Department -eq "Sales"}

Name                             Department                                     
----                             ----------                                    
{Numbers, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7...}      {Sales,IT,Accounting,Developers...}
```

Comment: You've created a single `PSCustomObject`, with two fields `Name` and `Department`. Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: I have excel file with 2 main 'Columns' (Number, Department) . ~ 660 rows. I will want extract these rows in [pscustomobject] and after use 'sort' and 'where' condition in order to be able to filter data by department.

Comment: You might want to consider whether it's not more appropriate to save the Excel file as a CSV, and then process it via `Import-CSV` piped to `ForEach-Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a single object with 2 properties, each of which contains *all* values of its associated column. Since `Sort-Object` and `Where-Object` sort and filter lists of objects by their properties there's nothing for these cmdlets to do here.

What you actually want to do is create one object *per row*.

```bsh
$output = foreach ($row in $ws.UsedRange.Rows) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name       = $row.Columns.Item(1).Value2
        Department = $row.Columns.Item(3).Value2
    }
}
```

Untested, since I don't have MS Office at hand here.